# setChangeListener method is not invoked

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i am new in blackberry developer. i am use a `pillsetbutton` and `pillfieldbutton`
but when i am click `pillfieldbutton` no any action is performed.I am using setchangeListener() method.but no any Action is performed.i am going Through this process.

```
public DemoPill() {

                        PillButtonSet objButtonSet=new PillButtonSet();

                        final PillButtonField objButtonField1=new  PillButtonField("NSE");
                       final PillButtonField objButtonField2=new PillButtonField("BSE");

                        objButtonSet.add(objButtonField1);
                        objButtonSet.add(objButtonField2);

                        this.add(objButtonSet);

     bjButtonSet.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            System.out.println("Hi ");

            if(field==objButtonField1)
            {

                System.out.println("This Is NSE Button");
            }
            else if(field==objButtonField2)
            {


                System.out.println("This Is BSE Button");
            }

        }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: set Field.Focusable and try ..

Answer (score 1):

You only can view the output of

```
System.out.println("ANYDATA");
```

in debug mode **not in run**. 
Try to debug it not to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing it on console. So without debugging the code you will never know if your click is consumed. So just use an event thread to see the output on your screen. I have provided you the sample just check it. It will show the output on your screen. You can also use `Dialog.inform(String message )` But its always good to do it on event thread.

```
public DemoPill() {

                    PillButtonSet objButtonSet=new PillButtonSet();

                    final PillButtonField objButtonField1=new  PillButtonField("NSE");
                   final PillButtonField objButtonField2=new PillButtonField("BSE");

                    objButtonSet.add(objButtonField1);
                    objButtonSet.add(objButtonField2);

                    this.add(objButtonSet);

 bjButtonSet.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
       // System.out.println("Hi ");

        if(field==objButtonField1)
        {
                     UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Dialog.inform("objButtonField1 button clicked")                 

            }
        });

        }
        else if(field==objButtonField2)
        {


           UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Dialog.inform("objButtonField2 button clicked")                 

            }
        });
        }

    }
});


  }

}
```

May be this will help cheers. :)